# Let $l\perp n$ and $m\perp n$. Then, $l=m$ or $l\parallel m$.

Tags: geometry

Let $l\perp n$ and $m\perp n$. Then, $l=m$ or $l\parallel m$.

How do I prove this?

I am allowed to use that two lines are perpendicular if they have orthogonal direction vectors, and that two distinct lines are parallel iff they have have the same direction.

We are not allowed to use pictures.

Also, we are working in plane Euclidean geometry.

Comment: Are you working in a plane?

Comment: Not nessecarily.

Comment: If not, then the proposition is false.

Comment: Then yes we are.

Comment: We are working in plane euclidean geometry.

Comment: How is this? Since $l\perp n$, $l$ and $n$ have orthogonal direction vectors. Let $u$ and $v$ be the direction vectors of $l$ and $n$, respectively. This means $u\cdot v=0$. But we know $v^\perp\cdot v=0$. This must mean $u$ and $v^\perp$ are scalar multiples. This means $[u]=[v^\perp]$. Let $m$ have direction vector $w$. In a similar fashion, $[w]=[v^\perp]$. This must mean $[w]=[u]$. This means $l$ and $m$ have the same direction. This means either $l=m$ or $l\parallel m$.

Comment: How, Jt3, do you get from $u\cdot v=0$ and $v^{\perp}\cdot v=0$ to $u$ and $v^{\perp}$ are scalar multiples?

Comment: Care to engage with my comment and my answer, Jt3?

Comment: I got it. I have no idea how I got that. I was just looking for something.

Comment: OK. Now: any thoughts on the answer I posted two days ago?

Answer (score 0):

Since "we are working in plane Euclidean geometry", here's a Euclidean proof:

Assume the hypotheses, and assume $\ell$ is neither equal to nor parallel to $m$. Then those two lines must meet at some point $P$. The triangle formed by $P$, the intersection of $\ell$ and $n$, and the intersection of $m$ and $n$, has two right angles, and a third, nonzero angle at $P$, so its angles add up to more than $\pi$ (radians; $180$ degrees, if you prefer). This contradicts a basic theorem of Euclidean geometry, so our assumption that $\ell$ is neither equal to nor parallel to $m$ must have been false. QED.